# Draw on a Canvas the contents of another

Tags: java, javafx

Have two JavaFX canvases. Is it possible to draw the contents of one into the other? One canvas is the composition of several images and shapes, and I'd like to draw a portion of such composition into the other without re-doing all the draws for the images and shapes.

Comment: You can simply clip the area of second and add the two canvas on your root.

Comment: @Mailkov you mean stack one over the other? But I need the two canvases separate. I just want to copy a part of one into the other without stacking them.

Comment: Would you get the buffer in GraphicsContext of Canvas and add it into other?

Comment: @Mailkov that sounds like what I want. Or at least part of such buffer. How is that done?

Comment: It's impossible to get buffer of Canvas because the function getBuffer() that return a GrowableDataBuffer is private and cannot be accessed from outside package.